# How would I append the text from a textfield to a textview and take a new line each time in swift?

Tags: swift, uitextview

I am trying to append the text from a textfield to a textview by tapping an add button:

```
@IBAction func buttonAddIngredient(_ sender: UIButton) {
    addIngredient()
    ingredientTextField.text = ""
}

func addIngredient() {
    ingredientsTextView.text = ingredientTextField.text! + "\n"
}
```

When the add button is tapped the text from the textfield disappears and then reappears in the textview. I am trying to add a new line each time the add button is pressed so the previous text doesn't get overridden. However, it is getting overridden at this time.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are only taking the updated value of `UITextField`, you are not holding the value to `UITextView`. Replace the below line

```
ingredientsTextView.text = ingredientTextField.text! + "\n"
```

To

```
ingredientsTextView.text = ingredientsTextView.text + ingredientTextField.text! + "\n"
```

Comment: I replaced the line with the one you are suggesting and I am now getting a Cannot convert value of type 'String!' to expected argument type 'inout String' error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ingredientsTextView.text = ingredientsTextView.text + ingredientTextField.text! + "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
ingredientsTextView.text?.append("Whatever text\n")
```